# GetListItems queryoptions - How to filter?

Tags: web-services

I have following code but I need to make sure that CurrentStatus=true is part of the code so I dont get the entire list. Is it possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName>States</listName>
            <viewName></viewName>
            <query></query>
            <viewFields></viewFields>
            <rowLimit></rowLimit>
            <queryOptions><QueryOptions/></queryOptions>
            <webID></webID>
        </GetListItems>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What type of field is CurrentStatus?

Comment: And I'd recommend downloading and installing CAML Designer, http://www.camldesigner.com/

Answer (score 2):

This xml worked. It's a Boolean field.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName>State</listName>
            <viewName></viewName>
      <viewFields>  
        <ViewFields>  
          <FieldRef Name="Title" />   
          <FieldRef Name="Zip" />  
         </ViewFields>  
     </viewFields>  
<query>
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="CurrentStatus" />
      <Value Type="Boolean">1</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
</Query>
</query>

            <viewFields></viewFields>
            <rowLimit></rowLimit>
            <queryOptions><QueryOptions/></queryOptions>
            <webID></webID>
        </GetListItems>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get some list data from a SharePoint list via the SOAP Web service interface.

Your query is missing the proper format / values 
here is an update that might work for you .

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <listName>States</listName>
            <viewName></viewName>
            <query>
                <Where>
                      <Eq>
                         <FieldRef Name='CurrentStatus' />
                         <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                      </Eq>
               </Where>
            </query>
            <ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                <FieldRef Name='CurrentStatus' />
            </ViewFields>
            <rowLimit>100</rowLimit>
            <webID></webID>
        </GetListItems>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`